# Is there a dictionary/tool where I can find advanced usage of simple words?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, learning

Is there a dictionary/tool where I can find advanced versions of simple words? (thesaurus is not enough)

For example,

- Untapped vs unexploited
- Lucrative vs profitable
- Prospect vs aspect
- Ferociously vs extremely
- Prone vs hurt
- doppelganger vs friend

I think it's helpful to look for such resources when I'm writing so I can enrich my vocabulary.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. With the exceptional the first two pairs none of these are synonyms. But even in the first two pairs nothing sticks out as a more advanced or simple word, whatever that means.

Comment: You want to find a "big word" that means the same as a simple word you have, right? **If so, say so.**

Comment: A thesaurus might help. I find Google's to be the best when it comes to fancy synonyms for simple words. If you want to actually learn big and obscure words, I'd highly suggest reading/listening regularly.

Comment: @vth What's Google's thesaurus?

Comment: @Kris what I mean is not just more alphabets, but also close in meaning (or close in some situations)

Comment: @Kris Look up "prospect synonym" on Google. You'll find a list of definitions for the word, along with a fairly robust set of synonyms for each definition.

Comment: @vth That is drawn (usually) from ODO. The definitions or the other information, including synonyms and etymology, are not Google's but fetched from other sources. AFAIK there's no Google's Thesaurus.

Comment: Google never provided any citations or sources for any of their definitions and synonyms, so misunderstandings are inevitable. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Could you please explain, with specific citations for each of your posted examples, how "thesaurus is not enough"?